# Use pandas to get count of field with respect to multiple columns like a pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

How can I achieve the following output from the given input pandas dataframe?

Input dataframe,

| country | name | email | job_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| US | Jon | `jon@email.com` | 123 |
| UK | Pete | `pete@email.com` | 234 |
| CA | Joey | `joey@email.com` | 345 |
| AU | Joe | `joe@email.com` | 456 |
| UK | Jim | `jim-uk@email.com` | 567 |
| CA | Jean | `jean@email.com` | 789 |
| GR | Mark | `mark@email.com` | 890 |
| FR | Ross | `ross@email.com` | 098 |
| JP | San | `san@email.com` | 987 |
| JP | San | `san@email.com` | 876 |
| CH | Son | `son@email.com` | 766 |
| UK | Jim | `jim@email.com` | 654 |
| US | Jon | `jon-us@email.com` | 432 |

Expected output dataframe (pivot table like output),

| country | name | email | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AU | Joe | `joe@email.com` | 1 |
| CA | Jean | `jean@email.com` | 1 |
|  | Joey | `joey@email.com` | 1 |
| CH | Son | `son@email.com` | 1 |
| FR | Ross | `ross@email.com` | 1 |
| GR | Mark | `mark@email.com` | 1 |
| JP | San | `san@email.com` | 2 |
| UK | Jim | `jim-uk@email.com` | 1 |
|  |  | `jim@email.com` | 1 |
|  | Pete | `pete@email.com` | 1 |
| US | Jon | `jon-us@email.com` | 1 |
|  |  | `jon@email.com` | 1 |

Comment: `df[['country', 'name', 'email']].value_counts().reset_index(name='count')`